# How to derive the KKT-conditions?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

The following non-linear optimalisation problem:

\begin{aligned}
& \quad \min x_1 \\
& \text { } x_1+x_2=0 \\
& \quad\left(x_1^2+x_2^2-4\right)^2=0
\end{aligned}

The task is to find the KKT-conditions.

The solution says that:

\begin{aligned}
& {\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right]=\lambda_1\left[\begin{array}{l}
1 \\
1
\end{array}\right]+2 \lambda_2\left(x_1^2+x_2^2-4\right)\left[\begin{array}{l}
2 x_1 \\
2 x_2
\end{array}\right]} \\
& x_1+x_2=1 \\
& \left(x_1^2+x_2^2-4\right)^2=0 .
\end{aligned}

I see where the first and last equations come from, but I do not see yet how the second one is derived.

Question: In the problem describtion it is given that $x_1+x_2 = 0$, why is is so that in the KKT-condition, the equations becomes $x_1+x_2 = 1$?

Feedback on this would be helpful!

Comment: This is a typo.

Comment: It turned out to be a typo indeed. Thanks for your answer